# how to create an algorithm that returns the String dayOfTheWeek in a given date WITHOUT using the java.util.Calendar

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to write an algorithm that allows me to determine what day of the week a given date is. I've seen on internet that I could import the java.util.calendar, but unfortunately I'm not allow to use that; instead I have to create the algorithm myself.
This is what I wrote so far, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Any thoughts?
Thanks

```
public class Date{

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;


public String getDayOfTheWeek(){

        int JANUARY =1;
        int FEBRUARY =4;
        int MARCH =4;
        int APRIL =0;
        int MAY =2;
        int JUNE =5;
        int JULY =0;
        int AUGUST =3;
        int SEPTEMBER =6;
        int OCTOBER =1;
        int NOVEMBER =4;
        int DECEMBER =6;

        int lastTwoDigits = year % 100; 
        int lastTwoDigitsDivTwelve = lastTwoDigits/12; 
        int lastTwoDigitsRemainder = lastTwoDigits %12;
        int lastTwoDigitsRemainderDivFour = lastTwoDigitsRemainder/4;
        int addDayOfTheMonth = day;
        int finalMod = 7;


        return (lastTwoDigits + lastTwoDigitsDivTwelve + lastTwoDigitsRemainder + lastTwoDigitsRemainderDivFour + day + month) % finalMod ;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Determination of the day of the week](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week), [How to Determine the Day of the Week](http://java.dzone.com/articles/algorithm-week-how-determine), [Zeller's Algorithm: Day of the Week](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~hutchins/csci230/zeller.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code may work, if you just make this slight change:

Change this line:

`return (lastTwoDigits + lastTwoDigitsDivTwelve + lastTwoDigitsRemainder + lastTwoDigitsRemainderDivFour + day + month) % finalMod ;`

to this line:

`Integer.toString(return (lastTwoDigits + lastTwoDigitsDivTwelve + lastTwoDigitsRemainder + lastTwoDigitsRemainderDivFour + day + month) % finalMod);`

However you might want to use the common mental calculation method. Here is a link to it's description on Wikipedia: [Mental Calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week#Basic_method_for_mental_calculation)

It is the most readable form and I think very acceptable for your project. Here is a short description:

(d + m + y + (y/4) + c) % 7
where:
d is day of the month, m is the month's number in the month's table, y is the last two digits of the year, and c is the century number.

The month table is the only information not given, and it is very easy to make, all you need to know is if the year is a leap year. That is also easily determinable using the following steps:

1. If the year is evenly divisible by 4, go to step 2. Otherwise, go to step 5.
2. If the year is evenly divisible by 100, go to step 3. Otherwise, go to step 4.
3. If the year is evenly divisible by 400, go to step 4. Otherwise, go to step 5.
4. The year is a leap year (it has 366 days).
5. The year is not a leap year (it has 365 days).

Or in code,

```
if((year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)))
```

will return true if 'year' is a leap year.

Comment: unfortunately my code doesn't work. I have the following error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.string

Comment: Change this line:    `return (lastTwoDigits + lastTwoDigitsDivTwelve + lastTwoDigitsRemainder + lastTwoDigitsRemainderDivFour + day + month) % finalMod ;`                                              to this line:    `return Integer.toString(return (lastTwoDigits + lastTwoDigitsDivTwelve + lastTwoDigitsRemainder + lastTwoDigitsRemainderDivFour + day + month) % finalMod);`

Comment: I've edited my post to contain the fix to your error.

Comment: If add your string the compier returns the following: illegal start of expression..perhaps this works: return Integer.toString (lastTwoDigits + lastTwoDigitsDivTwelve + lastTwoDigitsRemainder + lastTwoDigitsRemainderDivFour + day + month) % finalMod);

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week

> The tabular forerunner to Tøndering's algorithm is embodied in the following K&R C function.[10] With minor changes, **it is adaptable to other high level programming languages** such as APL2.[11] (A 6502 assembly language version exists as well.)  Posted by Tomohiko Sakamoto on the comp.lang.c Usenet newsgroup in 1993, **it is accurate for any Gregorian date**:

```
//js
function dayofweek(y, m, d) 
    {
       t= [0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4];
        y -= m < 3;
        return Math.floor(y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + t[m-1] + d) % 7;
    }
```

> The function does not always preserve y, and returns 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, etc. In contrast, the following expression

Comment: Please consider adding some description to help OP understand what the code means/is doing.